# Vuetify : ripple effect launched two times on mobile

Tags: vuetify.js

While trying my app with my android phone, I noticed that the vuetify ripple  animation was launched two times.

[Relevant codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/orobjQ)

Try it out with your desktop desktop : enable the dev console, then the mobile touch event simulation and "touch" the picture.

It happens everytimes on Firefox, or just sometimes with webkit based browser.

I tried to remove the hover effect, apply the ripple on th `<v-img>` element, but nothing happen.

Did I miss something ?